# C++ constructor call non-virtual function, let's say funcA, but funcA calls a virtual function, is it dangerous

Tags: c++

I know we better don't call a virtual function in the constructor since the derived class construction not started yet based on https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors , but what's going on if we call a non-virtual function in constructor, but the non-virtual function call a virtual one, is it dangerous as well?

If YES, then how can we avoid it, if the call stack for a non-virtual is more deep, we cannot be aware of this issue, right?

```
class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        funcA();
    }
    void funcA()
    {
        func1();
    }
    virtual void func1(){
        std::cout << "A func1" <<std::endl;
    }

};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    B()
    {

    }

    virtual void func1(){
        std::cout << "B func1" <<std::endl;
    }

};
```

Comment: Do you need a constructor at all?

Comment: It is really the same as constructor calling the virtual method. You can try to separate the construction and initialization, and use factory methods to deliver unified construction interface externally.

Comment: Doesn't the link explicitly give you a solution?

Comment: Do you have a specific need to call a virtual function implementation of the derived class?

Comment: Functions are not virtual during construction, regardless of them being marked `virtual` or not.

Comment: the virtual Base::func() is for common use, in some derived class, we may need to do some specific for derived class and then call Base::func() , something like Derived::func() { //do some speicific; Base::func(); }

Comment: It's not 'dangerous' at all. The result is very well-defined. However it may not be what you *expect.*

Comment: Depends on your definition of "dangerous".   Calling a virtual function in a constructor calls the version of that function for that class (i.e. if the constructor of `A` calls a virtual function `func1()`, then `A::func1()` is called, even if classes derived from `A` override that function).   This is true whether its the constructor that calls the virtual function, or another function that the constructor calls.     If you *expect* or *rely on* a derived class version of that virtual function being called - which won't happen - then the behaviour  is potentially dangerous.

Comment: You can create virtual functions also in the base class (instead of pure virtual functions). Those could print out an error message or abort the program or implement some functionality instead. Otherwise either document or simplify the construction, e.g. the derived classes call an initialize function of the base class in their constructor, or you can put the class inside another class as a member variable and call the initialization from there after the constructors (base and derived) of the variable have run through instead of in the base constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if we call a non-virtual function in constructor, but the non-virtual function call a virtual one, is it dangerous as well?

Yes. Take this example:

```
struct foo {
    foo() { proxy(); }
    void proxy() { call(); }
    virtual void call() = 0;
};

struct bar : foo {
    void call() override {}
};
```

Instantiating `bar` will most likely result in a runtime fault. It may print something like "pure virtual method called" and die.

> how can we avoid it, if the call stack for a non-virtual is more deep, we cannot be aware of this issue, right?

Not without analysing the code. You may find a static analyzer that is capable of catching this - or you'll have to do it manually.